# Using prior column to create new column in DataFrame creation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I know how to create a new column based on another column in Pandas. What I'm trying to do is create a new column based on another column at the time of DataFrame creation. Here is the code I have now:

```
rng = np.random.default_rng()
number_of_trials = float('10E+06')
simulations = pd.DataFrame({'true_average': rng.beta(81, 219, size=int(number_of_trials))})
simulations = simulations.assign(hits=lambda x: rng.binomial(300, x.true_average, size =int(number_of_trials)))
```

Instead of doing two lines to create the `true_average` and `hits` columns in the DataFrame I would like to do it just in the `DataFrame` object instantiation if possible. Everything I've searched for just tells me how to do it in two steps which is fine but I know this is possible in R so just wondered if Pandas had the same functionality.

I've tried to create a column based on doing a lambda function accessing the `true_average` column but it just stores the function itself as the value in the Dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just use the logic you use to create the original column (true_average) as the second parameter in rng.binomial:

```
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=42)
number_of_trials = float('10E+06')
simulations = pd.DataFrame({'true_average': rng.beta(81, 219, size=int(number_of_trials)), 
'hits': rng.binomial(300, (rng.beta(81, 219, size=int(number_of_trials))), size =int(number_of_trials))})
print(simulations)
```

Yields:

```
         true_average  hits
0            0.248803    65
1            0.253768    99
2            0.242576    67
3            0.277595    78
4            0.335829    80
...               ...   ...
9999995      0.267265    66
9999996      0.308596   100
9999997      0.279287    88
9999998      0.247802    79
9999999      0.269566    67

[10000000 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: This is possible but would need to pass `seed` to the rng to make sure the same values are being generated with each call to `rng.beta`

Comment: @MatthewBarlowe edited to include seed parameter in rng